# Openlayers/Angular; feature properties not updating

Tags: angular, openlayers

I have a selection interaction that gets features when clicked. When it's clicked I change a property to "true" in the feature. If this property is "true" a panel in a mat-accordion is expanded. The problem is that the panel is not expanded immediately, I have to turn off the layer and then turn on the layer to see the change. Does anyone no the problem here? Is it angular or the layer?

TS (my click interaction)

```
      let feature = event.target.getFeatures().item(0);
      feature.setProperties({isFeatureSelected: true});
      console.log(feature)
      });
```

HTML

```
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngIf="i < 5" [expanded]="feature.isFeatureSelected">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header collapsedHeight="38px">
              <mat-panel-title>
                {{ feature.namn }}
              </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers feature properties can be accessed with `feature.getProperties().isFeatureSelected`